# Subquery Returns More Than 1 Row, can't find any answer

Tags: mysql

my sql server tells me that subquery returns more than one row and i can't find ount what to do this is my query

```sql
select product_name from orders
    where (select concat(month,'/',day,'/',year) 
    as date from orders) = 09/15/2015
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: i'm trying to post the products in the date selected as concat @.@

Comment: Well, that (if it worked) would be more likely to give you all products if ANY product had that date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest query to get what you want, however (standby for an advice edit):

```
SELECT product_name 
FROM orders 
WHERE concat(month,'/',day,'/',year) = '09/15/2015'
;
```

Storing dates in that manner is usually not a good idea; it is much better than storing it as a string, but still not as effective as using a DATE type. Actually, with the current data structure this `WHERE` is probably better (assuming the fields used are INTs).

```
WHERE `year` = 2015 AND `month` = 9 AND `day` = 15
```

This should be able to take advantage of indexes, if they are present.

However, if this a relatively new project/database, I'd strongly recommend changing the date to a single DATE field.

Comment: thanks dude :) that's a great help :) Now i'm near done with my thesis project xD